# Efficient algorithm for intersection of map disorderly using key

Tags: c++

What is the most efficient way to intersect two maps by key?

Eg.: Given

```
map<int, float> m1;
map<int, float> m2;

m1[1] = 1.0;
m1[2] = 4.0;
m1[3] = 3.0;
m1[7] = 5.0;

m2[7] = 3.0;
m2[4] = 2.0;
m2[2] = 4.0;
m2[9] = 6.0;
```

I need an `vector<int>` with the result of the intersection!

The expected result will be: `2` and `7`

Comment: `The expected result will be: 2 and 7`-- result of what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the [Intersection of two STL maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772664/intersection-of-two-stl-maps) posting for my scenario.

```
template<typename keyType, typename leftValue, typename rightValue>
vector<keyType> intersectMaps(const map<keyType, leftValue>& left, const map<keyType, rightValue>& right) {
    vector<keyType> result;
    typename map<keyType, leftValue>::const_iterator itrL = left.begin();
    typename map<keyType, rightValue>::const_iterator itrR = right.begin();
    while (itrL != left.end() && itrR != right.end()) {
        if (itrL->first < itrR->first) {
            ++itrL;
        } else if (itrR->first < itrL->first) {
            ++itrR;
        } else {
            result.push_back(itrL->first);
            ++itrL;
            ++itrR;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Eg. to use:

```
map<int, float> m1;
map<int, float> m2;

m1[1] = 1.0;
m1[2] = 4.0;
m1[3] = 3.0;
m1[7] = 5.0;

m2[7] = 3.0;
m2[4] = 2.0;
m2[2] = 4.0;
m2[9] = 6.0;

vector<int> result = intersectMaps<int, float, float> (m1, m2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since keys are sorted, this is easy to do in O(n) time. just iterate through each of them, and whenever the keys are equal add that key to the vector and increment both iterators. Otherwise increment the iterator that has the lowest key.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is same as set intersection.
Loop through the first set, and consult if the the element is in the second set. 
The complexity is O(n lg m) while n and m are sizes of the 2 sets respectively.

You can get the complexity to be O(n) if you use unordered_map which is backed by hash table instead of red black tree.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of this as `m1` and `m2` already have elements sorted following gets a vector in `O(n)`

```
std::vector<int> v_intersection;

map<int, float> ::iterator i,j;

i=m1.begin(),j=m2.begin();

for(; i!=m1.end() && j!=m2.end() ;) 
   if (i->first < j->first)
            ++i;
   else if (i->first > j->first)
            ++j;
   else{ 
        v_intersection.push_back(i->first);       
        ++i,++j;
    }
```

Comment: Sad story is that std::set_intersection does *exactly* this, but it's unusable in this case without transform iterators.