# Intersection of two unordered_maps

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, unordered-map

Basically my question is the same as [Intersection of two STL maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772664/), but with two `unordered_maps`:

```
std::unordered_map<Key, Value> A;
std::unordered_map<Key, Value> B;
```

I'd like get the intersection, something similar to

```
std::unordered_map<Key, std::pair<Value, Value>> C;
```

where the keys are the values in both A and B and the value is a pair of the values from A and B respectively.

What is the fastest way to achieve this?  Currently I iterate over the smallest of both and query for the key in the second.  Fortunately often my key type is quite simple to hash, but I did not find a means to get the hash value of my key of the iterated map to spare the computation of the hash for the second (to be clear: I don't know how to recover the hash without recomputing it again, and where to find something like `find` with a computed hash as argument [1]).

Thanks.

[1] Yeah, I know, early optimization is the root of plenty of diseases.  Yet I'd like to know if this is possible, not an explanation about how this would be a can of bugs.  And actually, in some cases, depending on user input, the keys *can* be complex and costly to hash.

Comment: It's simpler and possibly faster if you have ordered `map`s.

Comment: Could you cache the hash value in your class?  In your hash function you could then check if the hash has already been computed and return it.  Remember to re-compute the stored hash if any of the keys change.

Comment: @Alan: yes I thought about that, but I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: I recommend that you put sample input and output to clarify, if certain key is found in A but not in B what should this algorithm do?

Comment: As any intersection would do: ignore.

Comment: With current STL you can't give pre-calculated hash to neither unordered_map::insert nor unordered_map::find. You may want to document your need and send a proposal to standards committee.
If this is really critical you may modify the implementation of STL that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you don't want to hear it, but I'm going to say it anyway: you should cache the hash value on the instances so that hashing reduces to simple member lookup. If the instances are immutable (or at least, the parts that go into the hash function are immutable), then the easiest way to do this is to compute the hash in the constructor.

Comment: You're right, that's not what I'm looking for :)  But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If the key was **really** expensive to hash, you could avoid one of the hashing at the expense of having A and B of type `std::unordered_map<Key, std::pair<Value, Value>>` from the beginning.(with the pair.second to a default constructed Value)

Supposing you don't need the original A and B once the intersection has been computed, you could just iterate through the smallest of the 2 (Assume B is the smallest) :

--> Move B in C

```
 for (auto it = C.begin(); it != C.end();it++ ) {
   auto res = A.find(it->first);
    if(res == A.end() )
        {               
            //Can't call C.erase(it) here as it would cause problem in the loop                 
            v.push_back(it); 
        }
        else
        {
            // Assign the second value of the pair to the value obtained in A.
            it->second.second = res->second.first;
        }     
  }
for( auto it : v)
  C.erase(it);
```

This would leave you with C filled with pairs where the pair.first is the value that was in B, and pair.second is the value that was in A

If you need to keep A and B untouched, instead of Moving B in C, just copy B in C.

Comment: Thanks, but that's really not the question, my maps are separate and cannot be just zipped this way from start.