# How to find the difference of two maps?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm trying to implement a similar function to set_intersection and set_difference but instead using maps as my date type for an assignment. I'm able to find the intersection, but my output for the difference function is not what I should expecet and I cannot figure out why. The two functions I'm using are as follows.

```
map<string, int> Group::Intersection(map<string, int> &tempSet, map<string, int> &currentSet){
    map<string, int>::const_iterator input_iterator;
    map<string, int> result;
    typename map<string, int>::const_iterator it1 = tempSet.begin();
    typename map<string, int>::const_iterator it2 = currentSet.begin();

    while (it1 != tempSet.end() && it2 != currentSet.end())
    {
        if (it1->first < it2->first)
            ++it1;
        else if (it2->first < it1->first)
            ++it2;
        else{
            result.insert(make_pair(it2->first, min(it1->second, it2->second)));
            ++it1;
            ++it2;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

map<string, int> Group::Difference(map<string, int> &tempSet, map<string, int> &currentSet){
    map<string, int>::const_iterator input_iterator;
    map<string, int> result;
    typename map<string, int>::const_iterator it1 = tempSet.begin();
    typename map<string, int>::const_iterator it2 = currentSet.begin();

    while (it1 != tempSet.end() && it2 != currentSet.end())
    {
        if (it1->first < it2->first){
            result.insert(make_pair(it1->first, abs(it1->second - it2->second)));
            ++it1;
        }
        else if (it2->first < it1->first){
            result.insert(make_pair(it2->first, abs(it1->second - it2->second)));
            ++it2;
        }
        else{            
            ++it1;
            ++it2;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Using these two lists:

```
cat 5
dog 4
bear 2
dinosaur 1

cat 6
dog 4
snake 3
lion 4
```

I receive an intersection of cat 5 and dog 4, but the difference gives me bear 4 and dinosaur 3. As far as I can tell, this is taking the two keys from the first map and matching them to the values from the second map but I cannot determine if it's my iteration or when I am putting the keys/values into a new map. Any advice would be greatly appreciated because I feel this should be a simple solution which I cannot figure out.

Comment: This assignment must be due tomorrow.  Have you talked to [John Smith](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274248)?  Is his name really John Smith?

Comment: [When will it be my turn](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3171112/when-will-it-be-my-turn)? **Right now!!!** Use a debugger first to narrow your question and specify which behavior you don't understand!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intersection of two STL maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772664/intersection-of-two-stl-maps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your set difference is that after you finish iterating there might be elements left in either list. So after your wile loop you need to add:

```
while (it1 != tempSet.end()) //add remaining elements from first map
{
  result.insert(*it1++);
}
while (it2 != currentSet.end()) //add remaining elements from second map
{
  result.insert(*it2++);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You handle the end case wrong. You stop as soon as you reach the end of *either* list, which causes you to omit entries. (Consider the trivial case where one list is empty. You won't output anything at all.)

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer as well as an attempt to seek clarification.

**Seeking Clarification**

Say you have:

```
std::map<std::string, int> c1 = {{"a", 10}, {"b", 20}, {"c", 30}, {"d", 40}, {"f", 40}};
std::map<std::string, int> c2 = {{"b", 200}, {"c", 300}, {"d", 400}, {"e", 500}};

std::map<std::string, int> c3 = map_intersect(c1, c2);
std::map<std::string, int> c4 = map_difference(c1, c2);
```

What do you expect `c3` to be?

```
{{"b", 20}, {"c", 30}, {"d", 40}}
```

or

```
{{"b", 200}, {"c", 300}, {"d", 400}}
```

The answer to that question will decide how you would implement the `map_intersect` function.

What do you expect `c4` to be? It is more natural to expect it to be:

```
{{"a", 10}, {"f", 40}}
```

**A Solution With Some Assumptions**

Assuming that you would like the value of `c3` above to be:

```
{{"b", 20}, {"c", 30}, {"d", 40}}
```

and the value of `c4` above to be:

```
{{"a", 10}, {"f", 40}}
```

The following implementations work in my tests:

```
std::map<std::string, int> map_intersect(std::map<std::string, int> const& c1,
                                         std::map<std::string, int> const& c2)
{
   std::map<std::string, int> ret;
   std::map<std::string, int>::const_iterator iter = c2.begin();
   std::map<std::string, int>::const_iterator end = c2.end();
   for ( ; iter != end; ++iter )
   {
      if ( c1.find(iter->first) != c1.end() )
      {
         ret[iter->first] = iter->second;
      }
   }

   return ret;
}

std::map<std::string, int> map_difference(std::map<std::string, int> const& c1,
                                          std::map<std::string, int> const& c2)
{
   std::map<std::string, int> ret = c1;
   std::map<std::string, int>::const_iterator iter = c2.begin();
   std::map<std::string, int>::const_iterator end = c2.end();
   for ( ; iter != end; ++iter )
   {
      if ( c1.find(iter->first) != c1.end() )
      {
         ret.erase(iter->first);
      }
   }
   return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define what the expected result of the operation you want, but there are a few things that have some smell to it:

```
    if (it1->first < it2->first){
        result.insert(make_pair(it1->first, abs(it1->second - it2->second)));
        ++it1;
    }
```

Does it make sense to create an entry indexed by `it1->first` that contains a number obtained by substracting the original value associated with `it1->first` and some unrelated value? In this case, the keys differ, do probably don't mean to aggregate the values.

```
    else{            
        ++it1;
        ++it2;
    }
```

If both maps contain the same key, you just ignore it? Should you be checking the associated values? In this case it actually makes sense to *merge* the results from the two maps. Other than that, I am not sure you would want to use absolute values. In my book `1 - 5` is not the same as `5 - 1`. Keeping the sign can help you determine at a later stage which of the two inputs had greater values for a key.

```
while (it1 != tempSet.end() && it2 != currentSet.end()) {
   …
}
```

What happens when one of the maps completes? Do you want to ignore the values in the other map? Consider the degenerate case: a map with N key-value pairs and an empty map, what should be the difference, an *empty* map? This is what you algorithm is generating.

Other than the algorithm itself, I would suggest that you took a methodic approach to testing. Build small test cases, from the bottom up: first two empty maps, then one empty one with one value, then two with one value that is the same/differs with the same/different values, then… By building test cases from the ground up you will have greater chances of singling out issues in your algorithm. For example the test case with one element in one map and none in the other (both directions) would have made you think about the terminating condition in the loop. Having two sets with the same key and the same/different values would hint if there is an issue with matching keys, and so on.