# Mismatch between two maps

Tags: c++, stdmap

Can I use `std::mismatch` on two maps?

In the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch), there is an example using strings and I presume it's similar for vectors.

The answers from [Intersection of two STL maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772664/intersection-of-two-stl-maps) are useful, but I am not sure how to use `std::mismatch` on maps.

If it is possible, can it be used for nested maps too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, a `std::map` has bidirectional iterators where as the `std::mismatch` requires input iterators as its parameters:

```
std::map<int, int> A {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 4}};
std::map<int, int> B {{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {4, 4}};
auto miss = std::mismatch(A.begin(), A.end(), B.begin());
std::cout << "{" << miss.first->first << ", " << miss.first->second 
          << "} != {" << miss.second->first << ", " 
          << miss.second->second << "}" << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
{2, 3} != {2, 4}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67a223e6ac38a373)