# Find common value in two maps without iterating

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have these two maps, each storing 10000+ of entries:

```
std::map<std::string,ObjectA> mapA;
std::map<std::string,ObjectB> mapB;
```

I want to retrieve only those values from the maps whose keys are present in both maps.

For example, if key "10001" is found in both mapA and mapB, then I want the corresponding objects from both the maps. Something like doing a join on SQL tables. Easiest way would be to iterate over the smaller map, and then do std::find(iter->first) in each iteration to find the keys that qualify. That would also be very expensive.

Instead, I am considering maintaining a set like this:

```
std::set<std::string> common;
```

1) Every time I insert into one of the map, I will check whether it exists in the other map. If it does, I add the key to the above common set.

2) Every time I remove an entry from one of the map, I will remove the key from common set, if it exists.

The common set always maintains the keys that are in both maps. When I want to do the join, I already have the qualifying keys. Is there a faster/better way?

Comment: 10K entries is not very many - I would go with the simplest possible solution, which will almost certainly be fast enough.

Comment: I'd most likely use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection or something like these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772664/intersection-of-two-stdmaps It really depends how often you need to do it and how often the maps change. Trying to cache the data might be worthwhile for some uses but overly complicated and more expensive than on-demand for others.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Usually, you would be right. But this function gets called far too often, so I need to squeeze maximum performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The algorithm is pretty simple. First, you treat the two maps as sequences (using iterators).

- If either remaining sequence is empty, you're done.
- If the keys at the front of the sequence are the same, you have found a match.
- If the keys differ, discard the lower (according to the map's sorting order) of the two.

You'll be iterating over both maps, which means a complexity of O(n+m), which is significantly better than the naive approach with its O(n log m) or O(m log n) complexity.